# Getting JSON Data From Url In Swift 4

Tags: arrays, json, swift, dictionary, swift4

So I am trying to get the data from this a website that is in a JSON format.
I can get the MTL and OBJ data just fine but the camera, aabb, and texture datas are giving me some trouble.

```
{
camera: {
  position: {
    x: -11.3932,
    y: 110.683,
    z: -18.2957
  },
  direction: {
    x: -0.40558,
    y: 0.40558,
    z: -0.819152
  },
  fov: 70
  },
aabb: {
  min: {
    x: -10.4467,
    y: 104.404,
    z: -13.709
  },
  max: {
    x: -6.74608,
    y: 111.39,
    z: -11.488
  }
},
mtl: "320a81679c114665a3eff9945968204d",
obj: "5f042b840ceb4a0211797eaf8cf75c01",
textures: [
  "e5dbadfc8a0feeaa79fc4c520b82d1e7",
  "0e48182cd907c44b36e21d624bf36b2a",
  "8d05159c75d0f5f7c8068bc928bb1a12",
  "db0fd6c20324aff4f145a58292874c4c",
  "2e01aa831a2c4b096ccac6b3fdf30279",
  "01840dc6d1548d496aab95701efbf69f",
  "31c7608579599b8bc85fa477d2dc7f9f",
  "cb877313d4525ced290a0560e372d1dc"
  ]
}
```

Here is what I have on the Swift 4 side of things.
I might have done the structure part wrong but I couldn't find anything online that would tell me how to make the textures data work, I know its a dictionary but I still couldn't find any resources on how to get the data. Everything I have tried just gives me an error saying incorrect format.

```
struct Tures: Decodable {
    let camera: String
    let aabb: String
    let mtl: String
    let obj: String
    let textures: String


init(jsontable: [String: Any]) {
    camera = jsontable["camera"] as? String ?? ""
    aabb = jsontable["aabb"] as? String ?? ""
    mtl = jsontable["mtl"] as? String ?? ""
    obj = jsontable["obj"] as? String ?? ""
    textures = jsontable["textures"] as? String ?? ""
}
}
        used = https://t0.rbxcdn.com/5e126639e3049c01ccd73fecb9416eb8
        guard let url = URL(string: used) else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            //let dataAsString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            //print(dataAsString ?? "")


            do {
                guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] else { return }

                let table2 = Tures(jsontable: json)
                let camera = table2.camera
                let aabb = table2.aabb
                let mtl = table2.mtl
                let obj = table2.obj
                let textures = table2.textures
                print(camera, aabb, textures)
            }
            catch {
            }
        }.resume()
```

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the camera you would need to create a custom structure XYZ for position and direction  (you can use the same structure for AABB min and max) and a property for fov. Textures it is an array of string, not a single string.For aabb you will need also a struct with min and max and use the XYZ structure for the property type:

```
struct Tures: Codable, CustomStringConvertible {
    let camera: Camera
    let aabb: AABB
    let mtl: String
    let obj: String
    let textures: [String]
    var description: String {
        return "Camera: \(camera) - AABB: \(aabb) - MTL: \(mtl) - OBJ: \(obj) - Textures: \(textures)"
    }
}
struct Camera: Codable, CustomStringConvertible {
    let position: XYZ
    let direction: XYZ
    let fov: Int
    var description: String {
        return "Position: \(position) - Direction: \(direction) - Fov: \(fov)"
    }
}
struct AABB: Codable, CustomStringConvertible{
    let min: XYZ
    let max: XYZ
    var description: String {
        return "Min: \(min) - Max: \(max)"
    }
}
struct XYZ: Codable, CustomStringConvertible  {
    let x: Double
    let y: Double
    let z: Double
    var description: String {
        return "X: \(x) - Y: \(y) - Z: \(z)"
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
let json = """
{ "camera": {
        "position": {
            "x": -11.3932,
            "y": 110.683,
            "z": -18.2957 },
        "direction": {
            "x": -0.40558,
            "y": 0.40558,
            "z": -0.819152 },
        "fov": 70 },
    "aabb": {
        "min": {
            "x": -10.4467,
            "y": 104.404,
            "z": -13.709 },
        "max": {
            "x": -6.74608,
            "y": 111.39,
            "z": -11.488 } },
    "mtl": "320a81679c114665a3eff9945968204d",
    "obj": "5f042b840ceb4a0211797eaf8cf75c01",
    "textures": [
        "e5dbadfc8a0feeaa79fc4c520b82d1e7",
        "0e48182cd907c44b36e21d624bf36b2a",
        "8d05159c75d0f5f7c8068bc928bb1a12",
        "db0fd6c20324aff4f145a58292874c4c",
        "2e01aa831a2c4b096ccac6b3fdf30279",
        "01840dc6d1548d496aab95701efbf69f",
        "31c7608579599b8bc85fa477d2dc7f9f",
        "cb877313d4525ced290a0560e372d1dc"]}
"""
```

---

```
do {
    let tures = try JSONDecoder().decode(Tures.self, from: Data(json.utf8))
    print(tures)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

This will print:

> Camera: Position: X: -11.3932 - Y: 110.683 - Z: -18.2957 - Direction:
>   X: -0.40558 - Y: 0.40558 - Z: -0.819152 - Fov: 70 - AABB: Min: X:
>   -10.4467 - Y: 104.404 - Z: -13.709 - Max: X: -6.74608 - Y: 111.39 - Z: -11.488 - MTL: 320a81679c114665a3eff9945968204d - OBJ: 5f042b840ceb4a0211797eaf8cf75c01 - Textures:
>   ["e5dbadfc8a0feeaa79fc4c520b82d1e7",
>   "0e48182cd907c44b36e21d624bf36b2a",
>   "8d05159c75d0f5f7c8068bc928bb1a12",
>   "db0fd6c20324aff4f145a58292874c4c",
>   "2e01aa831a2c4b096ccac6b3fdf30279",
>   "01840dc6d1548d496aab95701efbf69f",
>   "31c7608579599b8bc85fa477d2dc7f9f",
>   "cb877313d4525ced290a0560e372d1dc"]

Comment: Thanks man! I see what I needed to do and now I know what to do for the future. I had some issues while trying to use the website as the json usage but I figured out of I just scrape the webpage and use, "let son = ("" + WebData + "")" then it was able to read the information fine. Again, thank you for your help! :)